# How to enable @Scheduled jobs by profile in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How could I enabled scheduled jobs only in specific profiles?

pseudocode:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${job.cron}")
@Profile("prod")
public void runJob() {

}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: If you don't want any scheduled jobs just make a separate config for the `@EnableScheduling` annotation which is tied to a certain profile. If that isn't enabled the `@Scheduled` annotations are ignored.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea so enable scheduling by profile explicit. Still this is only useful if I don't want to have any jobs in test. Mostly I just want to exclude specific ones.

Comment: If you don't want the jobs annotate the bean with the `@Profile` insted of the method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should have one bean per profile:

```
@Component
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdJob {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${job.cron}")
    public void runJob() {

    }

}

@Component
@Profile("beta")
public class BetaJob {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${job.cron}")
    public void runJob() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using following approach.
Almost as you already did, but add colon and then the default value that should be picked if property not found. Here we use '-' as cron disable expression:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${job.cron:-}")
public void runJob() {

}
```

Then define cron expression in desired profile (for example using properties file).

Here is the application-prod.properties content:

```
job.cron=*/30 * * * * *
```

Here for prod profile it will be launched every 30 seconds and for all others it is turned off.

Comment: app is going down if i use the CORN_DISABLE expression "-". do we require any other configuration?

Comment: With SpringBoot it works out of the box, with Spring additional configuration is probably required. Look in the direction of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer or maybe PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. Default values syntax itself is available since Spring 3.

Comment: sometimes only cron is changed by profile and 2 beans for that is too much. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use spring boot version 2.3.7 and the solution to this problem is equal to the pseudocode you provided. You inspired their team :-).

```
// Enable sceduling
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my.main.package-Scheduler-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
}

// A scheduled job that runs only when profile "prod" is enabled
@Component
@Profile("prod")
@NoArgsConstructor
class ExpirationNotificationScheduler {

    // Just for test, run each 10th second or each minute
    @Scheduled(cron = "10 * * * * *") // second, minute, hour, day of month, month, day(s) of week
    public void notifyExpiredAccounts() {
        System.out.println("Yes, I am a scheduled job.");
    }
}
```