# How to combine @Scheduled with Profiles

Tags: java, spring

I've got a class that Spring finds via component scan and that has a method annotated with `@Scheduled`:

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    ...
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
    public void update() {
        ...
```

The value `60000` is ok for production, but in my tests I want it to be `1000`.
How can I achieve that? E.g., can I combine `@Scheduled` with profiles somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ... xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
... xsi:schemaLocation="... http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd ...>

<!-- Everything for "default" profile, including the bean with "@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)" on UpdaterTracker.update() and the "taskScheduler" bean -->
...

<!-- Activate this profile in Arquillian tests -->
<beans profile="arquillian">
    <!-- Update more frequently -->
    <bean id="updaterTracker" class="com.foo.UpdaterTracker"/>
    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="updaterTracker" method="update" fixed-delay="1000"/>
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
</beans>

</beans>
```

The first part defines the beans as usual, including an instance of the UpdaterTracker-bean that performs update() every 60 seconds. The last part is only activated in case "arquillian" profile is active, defining another instance of the UpdaterTracker-bean and a scheduled task that executes update() every second.

The solution is not perfect, because it produces 2 instances of UpdaterTracker and 3 scheduled tasks. It could be optimized by directly referencing the first UpdaterTracker instance in  so that we get 1 instance and 2 scheduled tasks.

However, this works for me and the solution has advantages: It does not require additional beans to be coded and can cope with multiple profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Make delay as property:

```
@Component
    public class Foo {
        ...
        @Scheduled(fixedDelay = ${delay})
        public void update() {
```

You may keep 2 property files. For example dev.properties and prod.properties
Spring will load one of it.

```
<context:property-placeholder
location="classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />
```

Comment: Thats a good idea, however, it won't work for me, because I use multiple profiles. So in production I just have "default" and for some of my tests I add the "arquillian" profile. This makes <context:property-placeholder
location="classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.properties" /> resolve to a file called "default,arquillian.properties", thus failing.

Answer (score 0):

Create two beans, one for production and one for testing and annotate both with @Profile accordingly like below

```
@Bean
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
@Profile("test")
    public void update() {
}

@Bean
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
@Profile("dev")
    public void update() {
}
```

In your unit test class you can switch between them by activating the relevant profile like below

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from "classpath:/app-config.xml"
@ContextConfiguration("/app-config.xml")
@ActiveProfiles("dev") //or switch to @ActiveProfiles("test") when testing
public class TransferServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private TransferService transferService;

    @Test
    public void testTransferService() {
        // test the transferService
    }
}
```

If @ActiveProfiles("dev") is activated only the dev @scheduled bean will be created otherwise test if the test profile is activated.

Comment: I think this works. However, rather than coding two different beans, I'm looking for a more elegant solution. Also, I my case I have two active profiles when testing ("default" and "arquillian"), which would probably cause two beans being instantiated. (Probably using multiple profiles is my root problem, but for the time being I'm stuck with that.)

Comment: This solution of combining `@Scheduled` with `@Profile` at method level will not work. AFAIK, there are two solutions:
 1) Use properties in `@Scheduled` and config these properties per configuration
 2) Use one class per profile and add the `@Profile` at class level.

See another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28782815/2185783